# Save an app for later download?

Tags: ios, applications, iphone, ios-appstore

I am looking for a way to create a wish list in the App Store, like you can in iTunes on the desktop.

Is it possible to do this on the App Store from an iPhone?

Answer (score 3):

That is actually a feature I've seen with "third party" app stores but never in the official App Store itself. I did however just check and I guess the closest in relevancy is the feature to "Tell A Friend". I presume you could simply tell yourself by emailing the direct link for that App Store application.

Answer (score -1):

Click the arrow next to the price and select "Add to Wish List".

Comment: This works in *iTunes* in which the OP already knows it is possible.

Comment: up vote 0 down vote
 

He ask about the iPhone app store. "Is it possible to do this on the iPhone App Store?"

Comment: He asked if it was possible to do "from an iPhone". As far as I can tell, it isn't.